# Angular 8 - What is the better way to compare arrays inside objects (JSON)?

Tags: json, angular

I'm developing a website (first time) with Angular 8 and I need some help.I'm receiving two JSONs from my API at the `service.ts`:

```
  getCurso(): Observable<Curso[]>{
    return this.http.get<Curso[]>(this.cursos)
  }
  getCursoConductor(): Observable<CursoConductor[]> {
    return this.http.get<CursoConductor[]>(this.cursoConductores)
  }
```

The JSON coming from `getCursoConductor()`:

```
{
"dato": [
  {
"id_curso_conductor": 1,
"f_inicio": "2019-09-19T05:00:00.000+0000",
"f_fin": "2019-12-20T05:00:00.000+0000",
"estado": "1",
"carnet_c": "l584f",
"f_caducidad": "2022-06-20T05:00:00.000+0000",
"f_emision": "2017-06-20T05:00:00.000+0000",
"id_curso": 1,
"id_persona": 3
},
  {
"id_curso_conductor": 2,
"f_inicio": "2019-08-20T05:00:00.000+0000",
"f_fin": "2019-12-20T05:00:00.000+0000",
"estado": "1",
"carnet_c": "8574h",
"f_caducidad": "2023-04-05T05:00:00.000+0000",
"f_emision": "2017-04-08T05:00:00.000+0000",
"id_curso": 1,
"id_persona": 5
},
  {
"id_curso_conductor": 3,
"f_inicio": "2019-10-09T05:00:00.000+0000",
"f_fin": "2019-12-10T05:00:00.000+0000",
"estado": "1",
"carnet_c": "2685f",
"f_caducidad": "2022-08-10T05:00:00.000+0000",
"f_emision": "2017-08-09T05:00:00.000+0000",
"id_curso": 1,
"id_persona": 6
}
],
}
```

And the one coming from `getCurso()`

```
{
"cur": [
  {
"id_curso": 1,
"nombre_curso": "Curso Vial 2019I",
"tiempo_vigencia": "2019-10-31T05:00:00.000+0000",
"estado": "1"
},
  {
"id_curso": 2,
"nombre_curso": "Curso Vial 2019II",
"tiempo_vigencia": "2019-12-15T05:00:00.000+0000",
"estado": "1"
}
],
}
```

As you notice both have inside `"id_curso"` and what I'm doing is creating html tables with the number or arrays coming from `getCurso()` and filling those tables with `getCursoConductor()`:

```
     <div class="container" *ngFor="let curso of listCursos">
        <h1>Curso "{{curso.nombre_curso}}"</h1>
        <table class="table table-bordered"> 
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Fecha Inicio</th>
              <th>Fecha Fin</th>
              <th>Estado</th>
              <th>Codigo de Carnet</th>
              <th colspan="2">Opcion</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let cursoConductor of listCursoConductor">
              <td>{{cursoConductor.f_inicio}}</td>
              <td>{{cursoConductor.f_fin}}</td>
              <td>{{cursoConductor.estado}}</td>
              <td>{{cursoConductor.carnet_c}}</td>
              <td><button class="btn btn-warning fa fa-pencil" (click)="fillSelect()" (click)="loadRequisito(cursoConductor)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editreqmodal" ></button></td>
              <td><button class="btn btn-danger fa fa-trash" (click)="Eliminar(cursoConductor)"></button></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
```

But it is repeating the cursoConductor data in both tables. What I want is show only the cursoConductor data for its curso, something like `if curso.id_curso=cursoConductor.id_curso`

Here is the code for the component.ts if needed:

```
curso: Curso = new Curso();
  cursoConductor: CursoConductor = new CursoConductor();
  listCursos: Curso[] = [];
  listCursoConductor: CursoConductor[] = [];
  constructor(private service: ServiceService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sortbyCurso();
  }
  sortbyCurso() {
    this.service.getCurso().subscribe((data) => {
      this.listCursos = data['cur']
    })
    this.getCursoConductor()
  }
  getCursoConductor() {
    this.service.getCursoConductor().subscribe((data) => {
      this.listCursoConductor = data['dato']
    })
  }
```

This is what I get https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOrWz.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, instead of having 2 collections separately, you can do something like that :

```js
// your typescript component :
sortbyCurso() {
    this.service.getCurso().subscribe((data) => {
      this.listCursos = data['cur']

      // ensure to call the getCursoConductor() when you retrieved the data
      this.getCursoConductor()
    })

}

getCursoFromId(idCurso: any) {
    return this.listCursos.find(item => item && item.id_curso === idCurso);
}

getCursoConductor() {
    this.service.getCursoConductor().subscribe((data) => {
      // we are filtering data received for only existing "id_curso" from listCursos.
      const listCursoConductor = data['dato'].filter(element => !!this.getCurso(element.id_curso);

      // then we update the actual listCursos by adding a new property "listCursoConductor" which
      // will contain all the associated data.
      const updatedListCursos = this.listCursos.map(curso => {
        return {...curso, listCursoConductor: listCursoConductor.filter(item => item.id_curso === curso.id_curso)};
      });

      this.listCursos = updatedListCursos;
    })
}
```

Then in your template html :

```html
<div class="container" *ngFor="let curso of listCursos">
    <h1>Curso "{{curso.nombre_curso}}"</h1>
    <table class="table table-bordered"> 
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Fecha Inicio</th>
          <th>Fecha Fin</th>
          <th>Estado</th>
          <th>Codigo de Carnet</th>
          <th colspan="2">Opcion</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngIf="!curso?.listCursoConductor">
            <td colspan="6">No data available.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngFor="let cursoConductor of curso?.listCursoConductor">
          <td>{{cursoConductor.f_inicio}}</td>
          <td>{{cursoConductor.f_fin}}</td>
          <td>{{cursoConductor.estado}}</td>
          <td>{{cursoConductor.carnet_c}}</td>
          <td><button class="btn btn-warning fa fa-pencil" (click)="fillSelect()" (click)="loadRequisito(cursoConductor)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editreqmodal" ></button></td>
          <td><button class="btn btn-danger fa fa-trash" (click)="Eliminar(cursoConductor)"></button></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Hope it will be helpful.

Comment: Wow, thanks man it works perfectly but I got one question, how can I hide the entire div instead of showing 'No data available.' ?

Comment: If you don't have any results, you can put a *ngIf in the table section like this: <table class="table table-bordered" *ngIf="curso?.listCursoConducto"> and remove the tr with the no data available. But if you want to hide the entire div, you can filter directly listCurso which contain listCursoConductor like this: this.listCursos = updatedListCursos.filter(item => !!item.listCursoConductor && item.listCursoConductor.length > 0);